# How to replace the partial view after save data in MVC C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my view when  user click the "create" button change the one partial view. In my view I created more then one partial views
Then after I save the data on partial view  I want to to relapse the partial view.

This is my partial view

```
@model LMS.Models.OrderTypeModels

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

 @{
      var defaulyDelivery = ViewBag.defaulyDelivery as IEnumerable<LMS.Models.t_COM_DELIVERY>;


            }


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)



    <table>

     <tr><td>   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </td><td>
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </td></tr>

    <tr><td>  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ddAddress)
    </td><td>
      @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ddAddress, ViewBag.defaulyDelivery as SelectList) 
    </td></tr>


        <tr><td>  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address)
    </td><td>
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address)
    </td></tr>

        <tr><td>  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Active)
    </td><td>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Active)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Active)
    </td></tr>

    <tr><td colspan="2">

 <input type="button" value="Save Order Type"   onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("SaveOderType", "Business", new { ordertype = @Model })'"  />

    </td></tr>
    </table>




}
```

this is my controller

```
 public void SaveOderType(OrderTypeModels ordertypePeolpe)
        {

            ORDER_TYPE orderType = new ORDER_TYPE();
            //orderType.

            orderType.KEY = lastOrderTypeId + 1;
            orderType.BS_KEY = currentbskey;           
            db.AddToORDER_TYPE(orderType);
            db.SaveChanges();



        }
```

if redirect to my first controller all the other partial views gone..
How Can I do it.

Comment: Based off of your question I cannot understand what you are trying to do or what is not working properly.  Can you let me know what isn't working?

Comment: You said "if I redirect to my first controller all the other partial views gone" but you are are only showing code for one controller method and it returns `void`.  We need to see the code for that *first controller*.